# JS Function to open / trigger opening of incognito window

Tags: javascript, jquery

ive been searching the web for any methods that are available to specific browsers that allow for the triggering of opening an incognito browser window or private browsing window?

I understand that there may be rules restricting this by the major vendors, but just intrigued as it would add some nice functionality to my app

thanks in advance